# How to trigger popup modal for first time visit site on rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-modal

Need Help!!!

It's make me get headache for a days, i need to set greeting modal for every visitor when they open my site for the first time, how would i do that

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain the cache on the local machine of the visitor and add count for the first time login on a day. To maintain the cache on the local you can use local storage 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage